# Can single line VBA If Then be followed by single line ElseIf Then?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Trying to follow a single line If Then with single line ElseIf Then, but the ElseIf Then's are not executed.

Does not work.  No error.  Just doesn't do the ElseIf's.

```
If WD = "Sat" Or WD = "Sun" Then State = "Z"
ElseIf HH >= 16 Then State = "A"
ElseIf HH >= 13 Then State = "B"
ElseIf HH >= 5 Then State = "C"
ElseIf HH >= 4 Then State = "D"
ElseIf HH >= 0 Then State = "E"
```

Works as expected:

```
If WD = "Sat" Or WD = "Sun" Then
    State = "Z"
ElseIf HH >= 16 Then State = "A"
ElseIf HH >= 13 Then State = "B"
ElseIf HH >= 5 Then State = "C"
ElseIf HH >= 4 Then State = "D"
ElseIf HH >= 0 Then State = "E"
End If
```

Is it possible to follow a single line If Then with single line ElseIf Then's?

Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications 7.1
Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2013
Excel 2013

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### VBA `If` statement syntax

While Mathieu's answer is technically correct - *this is not possible with if statements* - let me try to further explain why.

The reason your first example doesn't work is that VBA allows this syntax:

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim var As Long
    If True Then var = 5
    Debug.Print var
End Sub
```

Note that in the above example, no `End If` is required, actually it's not even allowed and constitutes a syntax error.

```vb
If True Then var = 5 End If 'Syntax error!
```

This means, that after a one-line `If` statement, VBA considers the `If` block complete. This is why the following example leads to a compiler error ("`ElseIf` without `If`"):

```vb
If Wd = "Sat" Or Wd = "Sun" Then State = "Z" 'VBA considers If block complete here
ElseIf HH >= 16 Then State = "A" '"ElseIf without If"
```

The reason you didn't see an error in your example was, that you had your snipped enclosed in another `If` statement.

In that case, it does indeed work, just not as you expected it would. Maybe the following example with correct indentation can showcase that:

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim State As String, Wd As String, HH As Long
    HH = 10
    Wd = "Do" '"Sat"
    If True Then '<-- Will always get entered -> ElseIfs will never do anything
        If Wd = "Sat" Or Wd = "Sun" Then State = "Z"
    ElseIf HH >= 16 Then State = "A" '<-- all of the following ElseIfs will not
    ElseIf HH >= 13 Then State = "B" '    get executed, because they belong to
    ElseIf HH >= 5 Then State = "C"  '    the same block as the "If True Then",
    ElseIf HH >= 4 Then State = "D"  '    which was already entered. In this
    ElseIf HH >= 0 Then State = "E"  '    case they are dead code and will never
    End If                           '    do anything!
    Debug.Print State
End Sub
```

VBA allows one-line `ElseIf`s inside an already started `If`-block like this:

```vb
If WD = "Sat" Or WD = "Sun" Then
    State = "Z"
ElseIf HH >= 16 Then State = "A"
End If
```

The reason for this is, that here the `EndIf` is mandatory, so the syntax is unambiguous. Using this, you can manufacture what is maybe the closest to an actual answer to your question:

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim State As String, Wd As String, HH As Long
    HH = 10
    Wd = "Do" '"Sat"
    If False Then
    ElseIf Wd = "Sat" Or Wd = "Sun" Then State = "Z"
    ElseIf HH >= 16 Then State = "A" 
    ElseIf HH >= 13 Then State = "B" 
    ElseIf HH >= 5 Then State = "C"  
    ElseIf HH >= 4 Then State = "D"  
    ElseIf HH >= 0 Then State = "E"  
    End If                           
    Debug.Print State
End Sub
```

This `If` statement looks a little funky but it works!
Maybe this is the workaround you are looking for. If not, there are further options by using line continuation syntax with `Select Case`.

### Alternative: `Select Case`

`Select Case` can also evaluate any condition just like if statements by using `Select Case True`, as showcased in the following snippet:

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim State As String, Wd As String, HH As Long
    HH = 10
    Wd = "Do" '"Sat"
    Select Case True:
        Case Wd = "Sat" Or Wd = "Sun": State = "Z"
        Case HH >= 16: State = "A"
        Case HH >= 13: State = "B"
        Case HH >= 5: State = "C"
        Case HH >= 4: State = "D"
        Case HH >= 0: State = "E"
    End Select
    Debug.Print State
End Sub
```

Also, by using `Select Case` you can actually go a step further and put the entire statement into a single line (up to 1024 characters):

```vb
Sub Demo()
    Dim State As String, Wd As String, HH As Long
    HH = 10
    Wd = "Do" '"Sat"
    Select Case True: Case Wd = "Sat" Or Wd = "Sun": State = "Z": Case HH >= 16: State = "A": Case HH >= 13: State = "B": Case HH >= 5: State = "C": Case HH >= 4: State = "D": Case HH >= 0: State = "E": End Select
    Debug.Print State
End Sub
```

Comment: _Technically correct_, the best kind of correct! IIRC line length is specified to max out at 1024 chars - good job showing more alternative expressions! Although, vertical code is arguably easier to read and maintain than horizontal code 

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, you are of course right about max line length, a little memory lapse on my part! Also, I agree with you that vertical code is usually easier to read. In some cases, when conditions and statements are short, code like the first one of my examples can be very readable imo :)

Comment: I wish I could upvote again for the indentation part. Kudos!

Comment: Ah ha,  The indentation does shed light on what is going on.
The ElseIf's are associated with the outer If True, not the inner one-liner If WD.  So yeah they will never do anything.
Wondering now if an outer If False and change the inner If WD to and ElseIf the way expected.  Don't know if I would do it that way but may give it a try just to see if it works.

Comment: Hi @NOYB, I just added another option to my answer. Thanks for your comment, your idea of `If False Then` made me realize this.

Answer (score 2):

No. The inline syntax is designed for short conditions and quick `Then` and (maybe) quick little `Else` statements. If the conditions are non-trivial, you need to use block syntax.

Inline syntax is a statement on its own; in VBA the statement terminator is a newline, so an `ElseIf` token cannot begin a line of legal code if the previous line didn't register as a block-syntax conditional.

Not sure what you mean with "no error" about the first snippet... it's a compile error... which prevents the code from running at all:

[image: 'Else without If' compile-time error message]

That said, there are still other ways to express these conditions:

```
State = "Z"
If WD = "Sat" Or WD = "Sun" Then Exit Sub
Select Case HH
    Case Is >= 16
        State = "A"
    Case Is >= 13
        State = "B"
    Case Is >= 5
        State = "C"
    Case Is >= 4
        State = "D"
    Case Is >= 0
        State = "E"
End Select
```

Comment: I meant exactly that.  No errors.  Turns out if that block of code is within another If block there is no compile error.  See if putting it inside an If True Then ... End If block and see if it still throws the compile error.
Not that it matters since can't do this anyway.
Think I stick with the way it is.  With the opening If condition Then and code on separate lines and the ElseIf's being single lines.  Short and readable.
Thanks guys.  Not sure who I should give the answer to.

Comment: Hi @NOYB, please look at my edited answer, I think it should clear up the conduction about your first code snippet.